# Collider is static

Tags: animation, physics, collision

I have a 3D model of a character with cloth physics hair, I bent him over to see if the physics looked ok and all worked well it seems except I cannot figure out why it seems the collider of the mesh is stuck in some way.

https://imgur.com/a/VZCh9rp

its like the mesh animates but the collider that is assigned to the mesh is static, I couldn't find anything anywhere about this specific issue. if elaboration is necessary shoot some questions, thank you.

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Are the modifiers in the correct order? Armature (top) then Collision (bottom) not vice versa. Or do you have a backup copy of the body mesh?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: @Blunder yes Armature is above collision, although i do have solidify and subdivide following those

Comment: @moonboots Done

Comment: Are you sure? This is *not* true for the file that you have uploaded. There is the *Collision* modifier above the *Armature* modifier. This order is wrong and causing the problem, see *mqbaka mqbaka*'s answer *below* (that's the opposite of *above* ;-)

Comment: oh yes sorry, i mistook the still weird physics behavior as the same issue, but it looks like something new. Thank you. @Blunder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because the collision is computed **before** the rig deformations are being computed.

Modifiers in Blender are non-destructive and sequential. Which means the order in which they are placed matter. That's also why you have the option to move modifiers around in the modifier stack.

In your blend file, the Collision modifier is on the top of the stack which means it is computed first meaning the physics are calculated without considering the deformations from the rig :

[[image: modifier stack1]

To correct that, just drag the collision modifier below the armature modifier :

[image: modifier stack again]

With the colision on top of the armature modifier :

[image: Wrong order]

With the collision below the armature modifier :

[image: Right order]